# Method and variable descriptions in PyCharm

Tags: python, intellisense

Is there a PyCharm parallel to Visual Studio's Intellisense feature that gives a brief description of a variable or method when I am trying to use that method or variable? If so, how do I view that description, and how can I write my own descriptions? In Visual Studio, for example, I can type three slashes /// which creates a summary block that pops up every time I try to use the documented method or variable.

Help appreciated!

Comment: If the function/method has a docstring, you can press ctrl+p while your cursor is inside of the function/method's call parenthesis.

Comment: Try this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-documentation-comments.html

Taken from the PyCharm documentation

Comment: EDIT: the command for me is ctrl shift space. But I only see the parameter names. Are there detailed descriptions for what each of those variables represent?